# Swift struct referencing another struct

Tags: swift, class, struct

I'm testing the following code in an Xcode Playground.

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}
struct Landmark: Codable {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int
    var location: Coordinate
}

var MyCoordinate: Coordinate = Coordinate.init(latitude: 30.1, longitude: 10.2)
var LandmarkA: Landmark = Landmark.init(name: "My Landmark", foundingYear: 2017, location: MyCoordinate)
var LandmarkB: Landmark = Landmark.init(name: "My Landmark 2", foundingYear: 2016, location: MyCoordinate)


LandmarkA.location.latitude = 12.1

print (LandmarkA.location.latitude) // 12.1
print (LandmarkB.location.latitude) // 30.1
```

Now if I convert this code to classes instead of structs.

```
class Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
class Landmark {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int
    var location: Coordinate

    init(name: String, foundingYear: Int, location: Coordinate) {
        self.name = name
        self.foundingYear = foundingYear
        self.location = location
    }
}

var MyCoordinate: Coordinate = Coordinate.init(latitude: 30.1, longitude: 10.2)
var LandmarkA: Landmark = Landmark.init(name: "My Landmark", foundingYear: 2017, location: MyCoordinate)
var LandmarkB: Landmark = Landmark.init(name: "My Landmark 2", foundingYear: 2016, location: MyCoordinate)


LandmarkA.location.latitude = 12.1

print (LandmarkA.location.latitude) // 12.1
print (LandmarkB.location.latitude) // 12.1
```

Is it possible to get structs to behave the same way as classes in terms of what location is equal to? If I change the coordinate either by doing `LandmarkA.location.latitude` or `MyCoordinate.latitude` it should set both `LandmarkA` and `LandmarkB`. This behavior works with classes but I can't use `Codable` in classes and there is less code needed to setup structs.

The last two print statements in the first example I would like to both be `12.1` and the same since it's both referencing the same object.

This is the only thing I can't figure out with structs. structs have everything else I need, Codeable, functions within the struct, minimal setup code, etc.

I would really prefer to use structs but if this isn't possible I will probably settle for using classes.

Any thoughts of how to achieve this?

Comment: You can go through https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/class-vs-struct-in-swift/ to fully understand the difference between the two.

Comment: you can use Codable with class as well.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq I saw that link but didn't quite understand it totally. Does that mean it's not possible to do what I want with structs? And I haven't seen any example or anything using Codable with class. Any link for that?

Comment: http://www.yudiz.com/encoding-and-decoding-custom-types-with-swift-4/

Comment: Apple prefers you to use `struct` but ultimately, the decision is on the developer to choose the best method for his/her needs. You can use `Codable` with class, but as of Xcode 9 Beta 3, the code synthesizer for class is buggy. Last I check, it does not handle inheritance properly

Comment: @CodeDifferent so if Apple encourages `struct` is there a way to achieve what I want with `struct`?

Comment: What you wanted was the fundamental difference between `struct` and `class`. You can use a pointer to a `struct` but then it becomes a `class` in disguise. Don't be afraid to go with `class` if you have a strong case for it

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but have a look at Chris' new post: [Struct References - Have your cake and eat it](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/references/)

Comment: Perhaps the replies you get will be more helpful if you can describe why you're trying so hard to avoid classes in favor of structs. As the prior replies state, reference / value is the distinguishing characteristic between class and struct, so trying to make structs behave as reference entities is always going to be swimming upstream.